# How to implement country selection using country_selection in form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use a country selection in a search form and was wondering that contry_select_tag doesn't work with form_tag

I've tried following

```
<%= form_tag new_search_path  :html => {:multipart => true} do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search_val%>
   <%= country_select_tag :country,[],["Germany", "France", "Austria", "Switzerland", "Netherlands", "Spain", "USA", "Russia"]%>

   <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<%end%>
```

And got the following error message

```
undefined method `country_select_tag' for #<#<Class:0xb6640828>:0xb5d06d5c>
```

Changing the `country_select_tag` to `country_select` I have no errors but the `:country` parameter in `params` stay empty

```
!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: GbmhaZAuSA3s88pTz+ZQJ6mxqZ1nrTpgSlSf40vttUY=
search_val: Test
country: 
commit: Search
html: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  multipart: 'true'
controller: searches
action: results
```

Do I need to use the normal `select_tag` and fill it up with the countries from a model or is there another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dropping the country part

```
  <%= form_tag new_search_path  :html => {:multipart => true} do %>
       <%= text_field_tag :search_val%>
       <%= select_tag :country,[],["Germany", "France", "Austria", "Switzerland", "Netherlands", "Spain", "USA", "Russia"]%>

       <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <%end%>
```

More information here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: Yes this one alternative possibility. But is there a way to use country_select_tag to have all the countries automatically.

Comment: Yes, if you set up a Country model and use collection_select it can pull the data from the model to populate the list.

Comment: I know, the idea was not use a separate country model. But after some considerations i decide to implement a country model with additional attribute fields for each country.